# How to return an item (if it exists) preferably over another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a system and I need a query to return preferably a client's cellphone number, but if they didn't insert one, return their home number.

Here's how the tables look like (they can't be changed):

```
CREATE TABLE Clients
(
    id_client int PRIMARY KEY, /* client's id */
    nm_client varchar(200), /* client's name */
    zipcode int
);

CREATE TABLE PhoneType
(
    cd_phoneType int PRIMARY KEY, /* 1 for landline 2 for cellphone */
    nm_phoneType varchar(60) /* "Landline" if the above is 1 or "Cellphone" if 2*/
);

CREATE TABLE Phones
(
    cd_phone int PRIMARY KEY,
    cd_phoneType int, /* 1 for landline 2 for cellphone */
    nu_phone VARCHAR(20), /* phone number */
    id_client INT, /* client's id */
    FOREIGN KEY (cd_phoneType) REFERENCES PhoneType(cd_phoneType)
    FOREIGN KEY (id_client) REFERENCES Clients(id_client)
);
```

Basically, if cd_phoneType = 2 for a client, it should return his cellphone number, otherwise return his other number. How do I do this in SQL syntax?

Here's the initial code I made:

```
SELECT nm_client, nm_phoneType, nu_phone 
FROM Clients
JOIN Phones ON Clients.id_client = Phones.id_client
JOIN PhoneType ON PhoneType.cd_phoneType = Phones.cd_phoneType;
```

Comment: How many clients are you selecting at any one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's turn the data from "2 rows with one phone number each per client" into "one row of 2 phone number columns per client"

```
SELECT 
  nm_client,
  MAX(CASE WHEN nm_phoneType = 1 THEN nu_phone END) as landline,
  MAX(CASE WHEN nm_phoneType = 2 THEN nu_phone END) as mobile
FROM Clients
JOIN Phones
ON Clients.id_client = Phones.id_client
GROUP BY nm_client
```

When you see how this works, now you can use COALESCE, a function that works through the argument list from left to right and returns the first non null argument it finds:

```
SELECT
  nm_client,
  COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE WHEN nm_phoneType = 2 THEN nu_phone END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN nm_phoneType = 1 THEN nu_phone END)
  ) as pref_num
FROM Clients
JOIN Phones
ON Clients.id_client = Phones.id_client
GROUP BY nm_client
```

--

If you're only ever selecting one client at a time a shortcut can be achieved by TOP ORDER BY:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  nm_client,
  nu_phone
FROM Clients
JOIN Phones
ON Clients.id_client = Phones.id_client
WHERE clients.id_client = 1234
ORDER BY nm_phonetype DESC --prefer 2 over 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It should only return one client at a time, so the last one works pretty well. Thank you for the input about the Coalesce command as well, I didn't know about it.

Comment: Awesome. If you ever want to do a report of all people and their preferred contact, the top one is the one to use. To mark an answer as accepted, click the faint grey tick under the number/updown arrows so it turns green. Welcome to the site! May it long be a useful resource for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT c.nm_client, c.nm_phoneType, p.nu_phone 
FROM Clients c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) p.*
      FROM Phones p
      WHERE c.id_client = p.id_client
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN p.cd_phoneType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
     );
```

You can also phrase this as a correlated subquery (because you want only one column and one row in the matched table).

Comment: That's another insteresting way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Quick q Gordon; did you do your order by like that rather than "order by desc" because of potential extensions if there were 3+ types that weren't necessarily numerically ordered (e.g. Prefer 2,1,3 in that order) ?

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . The OP does not specify that there are only two phone types, only that number 2 should be first.

Comment: Interesting; I parsed his post differently (he only ever talks about/defines two types of phone in e.g. the comments of the DDL or the opening sentence). One for future readers of these respective techniques to note

Comment: @PHTessmer . . . Is there a reason you no longer prefer this solution?